# How to Set value dynamically in setvar variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using SQLCMD mode. I want to set setvar variable value.
How should I set value in :setvar?
My Code are look like this :

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName AS nvarchar(180)
set @DatabaseName = '$(dbName)'    
print @DatabaseName     
:setvar DatabaseName @DatabaseName
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see below documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-2017

and below code from above

```
sqlcmd
:setvar  MYDATABASE AdventureWorks2012
USE $(MYDATABASE);
GO
```

so based on above your code should work fine...

Comment: I need to set value dynamic. "AdventureWorks2012" is static. My value set at runtime.

Answer (score -2):

To get current using database use code bellow:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName AS nvarchar(180)
SELECT @DatabaseName = DB_NAME()


print @DatabaseName     
:setvar DatabaseName @DatabaseName
```

Comment: Tried using same way but can't success.

Comment: Can you provide any details what is not working , how are you using this variable later on?

Comment: If you add this statement to the end of the script, :!!echo $(DatabaseName), you will set that $(DatabaseName) is set to @DatabaseName (not the actual name of the database).